# Scrollable Bitmap win32 Possible?

Tags: c, winapi, bitmap, scroll

I'm trying to display a Bitmap on a form, but the problem is I have to resize it (beforehand) for it to even fit. It's a large map (like an actual map...geographical), so of course if I make it really small just to fit on the form, it won't be readable. So, I figured my only option was to possibly add in some sort of scrolling functionality. That way I could the keep the full size of the image, and still have it contained with my form. I would just have to use vertical and horizontal scroll bars around a specified area of in which I could navigate the entire map. Keep in mind, I do need some room within the form for buttons, checkboxes, etc.

I looked around for some information on the subject, and I wasn't really able to find anything besides something on CodeProject. However, it was related to VC++ and dialogs, and I'm using C.

As of now, the only thing I can think of is to make a border-less second window (with horizontal and vertical scrolling enabled on creation), size it accordingly, and pin it to my main window. I could then place the Bitmap within entire size of the second window, and it should work like I want it to. Is that even possible? Does anyone have any suggestions on what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of scroll bars, I'd probably use dragging functionality like almost everybody does nowadays (i.e., user clicks somewhere, drags, and the map moves where they drag it).

As to how to do the scrolling itself: you can use [`ScrollWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787591.aspx) to move the existing part of the map, then `BitBlt` to fill in the vacated area(s).